# Splunk: setting up real time alerts

Tags: real-time, reporting, splunk

I need to configure real time alerts in Splunk but it shows only the scheduled option. How do I enable real time alerts? Is it lack of licensing? Can't find it in documentation.

[image]

Comment: What Splunk product are you using (Cloud, Enterprise, etc.)? What version?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any more information about your Splunk environment or your search setup, the two most likely possibilities that you can't set up a real-time alert are:

#### #1: You are running an old version of Splunk.

Real-time alerting was introduced in [Splunk v4.2](https://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAF33). Upgrade to the current version to use real-time alerts.

---

#### #2: You're trying to set up a real-time alert from a historical search.

A real-time alert can't be set up on a historical search. See [this solution on Splunk Answers](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/26272/changing-the-existing-dashboard-reports-to-show-real-time-alert.html#answer-container-26465) for more information, including how to change your search to a real-time search if that's what it should be.